# JavaScript Input Field Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I wrote validation code for a form, which goes:

```
function checkWholeForm(theForm) {
  // Create validation variables
  var valid = true;
  var validationMessage = "Please correct the following errors: \r\n";

  // Validate name
  if (document.getElementById('name').value.length == 0)
        {
            validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Name is missing\r\n';
            valid = false;
        }

//(and there's a few other functions)

// Display alert box with errors if any errors found
  if (valid == false)
        {
            alert(validationMessage);
        }

        return valid;

  }
```

and then in the HTML page, it goes:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm(this)">
```

and in the table is:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" value="" />
```

But when I hit submit, an empty text box doesn't trigger the alert. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: http://jsbin.com/uvepin/2/edit for the full HTML and JS.

Comment: `validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Name is missing\r\n';` should have double quotes if you want to add a `\r` or a `\n`. This is not the reason your script doesn't work. Please use pastebin or paste the complete script here.

Comment: @AC validationMessage is not defined, please rename it to validMess or define it.

Comment: Oops. Corrected. Still no joy!

Comment: You've renamed it to `validMessage` when it should be `validationMessage`. And please _don't_ use patsebin.com, use http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com so that you can also include your html/css and we can actually run your code.

Comment: @Kumar - `'\r\n'` is perfectly valid JS. You don't need double-quotes.

Comment: @nnnnnn :( this is a TIL moment for me...my bad.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Corrected, and JSBin link added.

Comment: FYI, instead of doing `someString = someString + "something else";` you can just use `+=` like this: `somestring += "something else";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, many issues, you are using getElementById, but your id is not set for the email box, also to do form validation, change from type = submit to type = button and use onclick instead of onsubmit

my edited version:
http://jsbin.com/ujeval/1/

Comment: You need the `return` to prevent the submit going ahead when validation fails.

Comment: That updated demo doesn't work - the form will _never_ submit because you always `return false` from the `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser's console (F12 in Chrome and IE; ctrl-shift-K in FF) you'll see that your code gives this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: validationMessage is not defined
```

...because you declared the variable as `validMess`. Then in your update to the question you renamed it to `validMessage`. But still your other code is referring to `validationMessage`.

```
// WRONG:
var validMessage = "Please correct the following errors: \r\n";

// RIGHT:
var validationMessage = "Please correct the following errors: \r\n";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JH8hg/

**UPDATE** to go with your latest update:

In your jsbin.com demo, you have attempted to add an `onsubmit` handler to a button:

```
<input class="button" name="send" type="submit" value="Send!" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm(this)" />
```

...but buttons don't have an `onsubmit` event so this should be added to the form element:

```
<form action="mailto:chandra.apoorv@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"
      onsubmit="return checkWholeForm(this)">
```

And that form element doesn't have a closing `</form>` tag.

And you forgot to give an `id="email"` to your email field which means you got a JS error when you tried to use `document.getElementById('email').value.length`.

**Working demo with those things fixed:** http://jsbin.com/ukepuh/1/edit

Comment: OK, answer updated to cover the problems in your demo. (Different problems to what you had in the code in your question.)